# Find the end points of a line segment in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations, coordinate-systems, parametric

I have a line segment in 3 dimensional space (x,y,z), and I want to find the 2 endpoints of this line segment. Is there a **systematic** way of doing this?

To be specific, I have the line described by the equations:

$$x+y+z=1$$
$$2y+z=0.5$$
$$x, y, z, \geq 0$$

Here's a picture (I want to find the red line's end points, or parametrize it with $t \in [0,1]$):
[image]

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize your curve with $x$, $y$ or $z$. For the $x$ coordinate you find
\begin{equation}
x \mapsto \left(x,x - \frac{1}{2} , \frac{3}{2} - 2x \right).
\end{equation}
Substituting for suitable $x$ gives you the "endpoints".

Comment: smart!! thank you!! do you have any idea how I could systematically do this, if the solution space to my system of equations is more than 1 dimensional?